# Junk data in <H1> tag on page with Google Map API in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I'm experiencing the H1 heading (first HTML element on page) being corrupted on a page with Google Map API v3 (using infobox as well). The text is being replaced with what appears to be garbage text and symbols.

The effect does not happen every time the page loads, just most times, and only in Chrome that I've found.

The H1 heading uses a TTF font loaded via CSS. If I remove this formatting, the problem does not occur.

CSS:
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'als';
      src: url('/wedding/assets/alsscrp.ttf');
    }

PHP / HTML:

```
<?php

$tpTitle="Venue";
$lastUpdate="13th December 2014";

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wedding/en/head-en.php');

?>    

<style type="text/css">
    html, body {height: 100%;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>

<H1>Venue</H1>
<p>etc...
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div class="infobox-wrapper">
        <div id="infoboxChurch" class="info">
            <h1>St. Johanniskirche</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions, map;

        mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.185,8.513),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        // Church
        var Church, infoboxChurch;
        Church = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.180007, 8.508152),
            map: map,
            icon: {
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60,50),
                url: "/wedding/assets/church.png",
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 25)
            },
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title:"St. Johannskirche"
        });

        infoboxChurch = new InfoBox({
            content: document.getElementById("infoboxChurch"),
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 150,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
            zIndex: null,
            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(Church, 'click', function() {
            infoboxChurch.open(map, this);
            map.panTo(loc);
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

head-en.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_GB">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $tpTitle ?></title> 
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-eqiuv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="/wedding/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <meta id="author" content="">   
        <meta id="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>">
        <meta name="DC.date.issued" <?php echo 'content="'.$lastUpdate.'"';?> >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wedding/assets/wedding.css">

        <!-- jQuery loaded either externally or locally asap to allow selective js loading and light box -->
        <script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


        <!--[if lt IE9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- link change for current page -->
        <script src="/assets/js/fade.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       

    </head>

<body>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="little-head">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="page-link" href="/wedding/en/welcome.php">Welcome</a>
            <li><a class="page-link" href="/wedding/en/contact.php">Contact us</a>
            <li><a class="page-link" href="/wedding/en/timings.php">Venue</a>   
            <li><a class="page-link" href="/wedding/en/travel.php">Travel</a>
            <li><a class="page-link" href="/wedding/en/hotels.php">Accomodation</a>
            <li><a class="page-link" href="/wedding/en/faqs.php">FAQs</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="seal">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the HTMl as well? Not all of it, just the `h1` element, its parents etc.

Comment: I've found that in the case of junk being written, if I resize the chrome window or switch to another tab for a length of time and then return, the title get redrawn correctly... Seems to be a Chrome bug, but no idea where the source is. I've tried moving all js down to the bottom of the page which makes no difference.

Comment: If I remove the Google map container <div id="map-canvas"></div>, leaving all other js and font references the problem disappears. It seems to be a conflict: Chrome/TTF/Google maps code